# Code behind doesn't work as XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm learning WPF and I have some troubles with it. I made this XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateTest">
    <Button Margin="10"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Content="{Binding Path=Text}">
      <Button.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" />
      </Button.Effect>
    </Button>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel">
  <TextBox x:Name="TextBox"
           Margin="10">TextBox</TextBox>

  <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=.}"
                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TemplateTest}" />
</StackPanel>
```

and the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var Resource = this.Resources["TemplateTest"] as DataTemplate;

        StackPanel.Children.Add(
            new ContentControl()
            {
                Content = new Binding()
                {
                    ElementName = "TextBox",
                    Path = new PropertyPath(".")
                },

                ContentTemplate = Resource,
            });
    }
}
```

[image: picture]

My problem is that the textbox's text only appear in the XAML defined control.
How to make it work in the code behind too?

Comment: Do you get any binding errors? And does it work if you remove the XAML copy of the control?

Comment: It doesn't work if I remove it, but I noticed this just now:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object' ''Binding' (HashCode=23914501)'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem='Binding' (HashCode=23914501); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the `ContentControl.Content` to the `Binding`, which is not the same as binding the `Content` property to a value.

To bind a property in the code behind, you need syntax like this:

```
var newControl new ContentControl();
newControl.ContentTemplate = Resource;

Binding b = new Binding();
b.ElementName = "TextBox";
b.Path = new PropertyPath(".");

myContentControl.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, b);
```